# Return multiple response from a single function in Node (sails js)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I am developing a web application using Angular js and Sails. Now I struck with an issue.In my application there is a menu, which displays different count values from database.Plz see my back

```
getAllCountMyProfile: function(req,res){
UsertokenService.checkToken(req.get('user-token'), function (err, tokenCheck) {
var userId = tokenCheck.tokenDetails.userId;
 var query = "select (select count(*) FROM review WHERE userId="+ userId +" AND approvalStatus = 'approved') AS reviewReceived ,"+
      " (select count(*) FROM review WHERE reviewerId="+ userId +" ) AS reviewPenned, "+
      "(select count(*) FROM photos WHERE userId="+ userId +" AND accessType='private' AND status='active') AS privatePhotoCount, "+
      "(select count(*) FROM photos WHERE userId="+ userId +" AND accessType='public' AND status='active') AS publicPhotoCount";
 Review.query(query, function (err, photoReviewCount) {
        if(err){
            console.log("Error"+ err);
        }
        else{

            return res.json(200, {status:4, message:'success',data1:photoReviewCount});
        }
    });
UserService.checkVideoLimit(userId, function (err, videoCount)
       {

        var noVideos=videoCount.data;
        console.log("Video count "+noVideos);
        return res.json(200, {status: 1, data2: videoCount});

    });
var query="SELECT sum(rating) AS totalRating,COUNT(*) AS totalCount FROM review where userId=" +userId+ "";
       Review.query(query, function (err, avgRating) {
        if(err){
            console.log("Error"+ err);
        }
        else{
            var rating=JSON.stringify(result);
            var totalRating=result[0].totalRating;
            var count=result[0].totalCount;
            var avgRatingValue=(totalRating/count).toFixed(2);
            console.log(totalRating,count);
            console.log("avgRating"+rating);
            return res.json(200, {status:4, message:'success',data3:avgRating});
        }
    });
   });`
}
```

If i execute each return response i got the result. If i Execute the above query , i got error message on console as
"Can't set headers after they are sent."
I need the result data1,data2, data3. what is the solution to obtain this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot set the response more than one time. Either you can use res.write and edit the response for queries and then send it with res.end() or you can change your code to send the response only once. Something like this:

```
res.status(200).json({
     "data":{
          "data1":photoReviewCount,
          "data2":videoCount,
           "data3":avgRating
            }
})
```